# ExifInterface problem on Droid

Tags: android, exif, android-camera

I'm using Android's Native Camera app to take a picture and save it on the sdcard.

```
Intent cameraintent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "test.jpg");
cameraintent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
startActivityForResult(cameraintent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
```

Now after saving the image, it seems to lose all EXIF information. When I try to retrieve the exif info like this:

```
ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/test.jpg");
String exifOrientation = exif.getAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION);
```

It returns exifOrientation = 0 (i.e ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED ), whereas it should return 6.

However, this code works perfectly well on other android phones (apart from Droid).

Comment: have you tried reading the EXIF data from something else? (regular computer?) it could just be that the Droid doesn't save this data.  Each Android distro has its quirks.

Comment: @willytale I right clicked on the image > properties > summary. I could see only width, height, horizontal & vertical resolutions. But when I ran the same code on a Xperia X10 mini, I could see a lot more info like creation timestamp, camera model, color representation etc. (I don't have any other tools to read EXIF data on windows)